# Loop through array Breadth search fashioned

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

the title of the question might be a little bit missleading but I am not sure how to describe my problem.

I want to restructure the keys of an array such that the loop will jump with the following pattern:

Example 1:

```
keys from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 will lead to 1,9,5,3,7,2,6,4,8
```

- take the first element - 1
- take the last element - 9
- take the middle (1+9)/2 = 5
- go to the first half and take the middle of 1 and 5 - 3
- jump to the second half and take the middle of 5 and 9 - 7
- jump back to the first half of the first half and take 2
- jump back to the first half of the second half and take 6
- jump back to the second half of the first half and take 4
- jump back to the second half of the second half and take 8

Of course, this is an idealized example where everything is nicely dividable. If this is not the case you have to floor and ceil to get the new elements to divide.

Example 2:

```
key from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 will lead to 1,10,5,6,3,8,2,7,4,9
```

With my small knowledge about algorithm and datastructures I tried to use recursion/divide and conquer but I did not manage to realize the jumps between the halfs.

So I think I have to add parameters like the length of the divided halfs an the positions but here I am lost for implementation.

The interesting question for me is: Is my thinking to complicated and is there a much easier solution? Or is this problem really this complex?

I am happy for any advise on literature ore code snippets to try it.

Thanks and best regards
Stephan

Comment: You need to better describe your problem, with maybe at least the step from one of your example, because with the current explanation, it is very hard to see how you go from your « key » to your final array,

Comment: I expanded the explanation. I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: I think you can do so by queuing tuples of (lower, upper) pairs, but it probably won't always give exactly the results you want. It would be much easier to get first the 1/2 index, then the 1/4 index, then 1/8, then later 3/4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can implement this algorithm by a recursive or divide-and-conquer. But you can do this elegantly using a breadth-first search. Below is python pseudocode, where you have a queue whose elements are intervals.

```python
#initialize queue Q with the whole interval
n = len(your_list)

# breadth first search
Q.push([0, n-1])
while Q not empty:
    itv = q.pop_front()
    process(itv)     # print the middle element of interval itv, etc.
    itv_1, itv_2 = divide_interval_into_halves(itv)
    if len(itv_1) > 0:
        Q.push(itv_1)
    if len(itv_1) > 0:
        Q.push(itv_2)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: hey cntswj, thanks for the code, I will try it as soon as I am back at my office computer.